# Fstream Couldn't Open File

Tags: windows, c++11, user-interface, winapi

After saving file with widows.h save dialog and fstream in other directory I couldn`t open file in program directory.

```cpp
        ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
        ofn.hwndOwner = hMainWindow;
        ofn.lpstrFilter = L"Text Files (*.txt)\0*.txt\0Word Files (*.rtf)\0*.rtf\0";
        ofn.lpstrFile = FileName;
        ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
        ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_NAME_STRING;
        ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
        ofn.lpstrDefExt = L"txt";
        ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;

        if (GetSaveFileName(&ofn) == TRUE) {

            std::fstream file;

            file.open(FileName, std::ios::out);

            //Write To File
        
            file.clear();
            file.close();
        }
```

```cpp
        std::fstream code;
        
        code.open("CodeTemplate.template", std::ios::in);
        
        //ERROR: File Couldn't Open, But File Exists in Program Directory
        
        code.clear();
        code.close();
```

If I Copy That File "CodeTemplate.template" To directroy that have been selected in save dialog file opens.

Answer (score 1):

`GetSaveFileName()` returns an *absolute* path to the selected file. So you are passing an *absolute* path to the output `fstream` to create the file.

But, you are passing a *relative* path to the input `fstream` to open the file.  Since that is failing, it is likely that the calling process' *current working directory* is not pointing where you are expecting.

You even said yourself that you have to "*Copy [CodeTemplate.template] To directroy that have been selected in save dialog*" to make the file open correctly. Which means that file does not exist in the folder where the *working directory* is pointing at.

In short, you should never rely on relative paths when creating/opening files. The *working directory* is volatile, it can change dynamically, and so it may not always point where you are expecting. Always use absolute paths.

Comment: How  get current absolute directory before calling ```GetSaveFileName()```

Comment: It is your responsibility to keep track of the paths of the files you create, or else just ask the user, such as with `GetOpenFileName()`

Comment: [CodeTemplate.template] File is file to work with program only , but not the user

Comment: I Found Function ```GetCurrentDirectory()```

Comment: [`GetModuleFileNameW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamew) returns the fully qualified path name to the module. Strip the file name portion to get the directory. Keep in mind that you no longer control the path, and need to be prepared that it cannot be represented using any ANSI encoding. Use the [`open`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) overload that accepts a `std::filesystem::path` argument.

Comment: No, `GetCurrectDirectory` is useless, and it's best to forget that you ever knew it existed. There is no problem where `GetCurrentDirectory` is a solution.

Comment: ```GetCurrectDirectory()``` Solved My Problem

Comment: It didn't. You merely ignore the fact that making a problem go away and solving a problem are entirely different things. The current working directory is process-global state, and any thread can change it **at any time**. If you need a fully qualified path name relative to the executable module, get the fully qualified path name to the module and take it from there.